# Text File Logging in MVC using standard Libraries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging

I'm trying to figure out how to do logging to a flat txt file in MVC.

I'm not asking for the best out there solution. I'm asking for a point in the right direction.

I've got an idea about having a singleton class handling all my logging.

I essentially just want to call a method called

```
alogger = Logger.GetLogger();
aLogger.Log("some message",enum.serverity)
```

whenever I need to log something to the file. and then just let the singelton handle how to write to the file and so on.

But then I started looking in to the microsoft.extensions.logging library hoping I could outsource most of my logging to some standard already in NuGet.

however I feel overwhelmed by the complexity of that library and are thinking about just doing my own small thread based logging. as it seems the simpler solution for my simple needs.
Are there any simple guides out there how to archive what I want but still using the standard library that doesn't look like we are building a rocket of a logger ? 
is there a better more simple approach to this that I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your questions have one simple answer - use [Log4Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/) library.

This is the simplest implementation I've done in one of the projects:

**ILogger.cs**

```
public interface ILogger
    {
        void Info(string message);

        void Warn(string message);

        void Debug(string message); 

        void Error(string message);

        void Error(Exception exception);

        void Fatal(string message);
    }
```

**Logger.cs**

```
public class Logger : ILogger
    {
        #region Properties   
        private readonly ILog log;   //ILog refers to interface from log4net library

        //Singleton Instance of Logger Class
        private static readonly object threadLock = new Object();
        private static Lazy<Logger> instance;

        public static Logger Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    lock (threadLock)
                    {
                        instance = new Lazy<Logger>(() => new Logger());
                        return instance.Value;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return instance.Value;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        //Private constructor to restrict from any instance creation
        private Logger()
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            log = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
            //log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        public void Info(string message)
        {
            log.Info(message);
        }

        public void Warn(string message)
        {
            log.Warn(message); 
        }

        public void Debug(string message)  
        { 
            log.Debug(message);
        }

        public void Error(string message)
        {
            log.Error(message);
        }

        public void Error(Exception exception)
        {
            log.Error(exception);
        }

        public void Fatal(string message)
        {
            log.Fatal(message);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**App.Config**

```
<configSections>
    <!--- Specifying the configuration information about the XML tag "log4net" -->
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
 </configSections>



 <!---log4Net configuration for enabling logs to be stored in different modes -->
  <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="consoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger -%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="filelogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    </appender>

    <appender name="rollingFilelogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\SpecifyLocation\SpecifyFileName.log" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="'Test_APILogs-'ddMMyyyy'.log'" />
      <!--<staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />-->

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger -%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="dblogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    </appender>

    <!---Root element where we specify the appenders (providers) that stores the logs.
    The various logging levels provided are:
    OFF - nothing gets logged (cannot be called)
    FATAL
    ERROR
    WARN
    INFO
    DEBUG
    ALL - everything gets logged (cannot be called)
    -->
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <!--<appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />-->
      <!--<appender-ref ref="filelogAppender" />-->
      <appender-ref ref="rollingFilelogAppender" />
      <!--<appender-ref ref="dblogAppender" />-->
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost, Route("add")]
        public IHttpActionResult AddEmployee(AddEmployeeRequestDTO request)
        {
            try
            {
                if (request == null)
                    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ErrorCodes.E002);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
#if (DEBUG)
                Logger.Instance.Error(ex);
                throw ex;

#endif
                //Logger.Instance.Error(ex);
                //return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ErrorCodes.E001);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You got me pointed in a good direction :) I did some research on the Log4Net but ended up using NLog instead. more simple usage, faster and as far as I could find just as flexible if not more.

Comment: Yes, you can also use NLog. Both are same however, NLog has more active user support. Cheers :)